# Python scatterplot with legend

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a legend for my scatterplot that matches the colors set in the plot. When I run my code I get two plots, and the colors dont match. Can someone help me fix this?

```
#import files and format them (you can skip this- its just simulating my dataset)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
d = {'vote': [100, 50,1,23,55,67,89,44], 
     'ballot': ['a','Yes','a','No','b','a','a','b'],
     'whichballot':[1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2]}
dfwl=pd.DataFrame(d)

dfwl['whichballot'] = dfwl['whichballot'].astype('category').cat.codes
dfwl['ballot'] = dfwl['ballot'].astype('category')
dfwl['vote'] = dfwl['vote'].astype('int')
dfwl=pd.DataFrame(dfwl.reset_index())
dfwl=dfwl[pd.notnull(dfwl['ballot'])] 
###END DATA FORMATTING    

plt.scatter(dfwl.ballot, dfwl.vote, c=dfwl.whichballot)
plt.margins(x=0.8)
plt.show()
plt.table(cellText=[[x] for x in set(dfwl.whichballot)], 
          loc='lower right',
          colWidths=[0.2],
          rowColours=['green','yellow','purple'],
        rowLabels=['label%d'%x for x in set(dfwl.whichballot)])
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe try the `legend` attribute instead? https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html

Comment: Thanks, just tried it, but couldnt get it to do what I needed.... it does make me think the problem is in how the colors are specified however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your problem. But I found two issues here:

1. You called `plt.table` after `plt.show()`. `plt.show()` will display your figure based on previous lines without table. `plt.table` will make a new plot with just the table. That explains why you "get two plots".
2. Your `set(dfwl.whichballot)` has only two values `[0, 1]`. Therefore, you legend will only display color at index 0 and 1 of your `rowColours`, which is `['green','yellow']`. `purple` is useless here.

Here is the code with simple edits which may give you what you want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
d = {'vote': [100, 50,1,23,55,67,89,44], 
     'ballot': ['a','Yes','a','No','b','a','a','b'],
     'whichballot':[1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2]}
dfwl=pd.DataFrame(d)

dfwl['whichballot'] = dfwl['whichballot'].astype('category').cat.codes
dfwl['ballot'] = dfwl['ballot'].astype('category')
dfwl['vote'] = dfwl['vote'].astype('int')
dfwl=pd.DataFrame(dfwl.reset_index())
dfwl=dfwl[pd.notnull(dfwl['ballot'])] 
###END DATA FORMATTING    

plt.scatter(dfwl.ballot, dfwl.vote, c=dfwl.whichballot)
plt.margins(x=0.8)
plt.table(cellText=[[x] for x in set(dfwl.whichballot)], 
          loc='lower right',
          colWidths=[0.2],
          rowColours=['purple','yellow','green'],
          rowLabels=['label%d'%x for x in set(dfwl.whichballot)])
plt.show()
```

[image]